# How to get BTC current price data from Coinbase Api?

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to get BTC current price from the following api:
"https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json"

```
function CoinbaseBTCPrice(){
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json",
    success: function(bitcoinPrice){
        console.log(bitcoinPrice.bpi.USD.rate)
        }
    })
}
```

When I try to do this it says that the data I am looking for is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the returned JSON string first using `JSON.parse`. Find out more in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

```js
CoinbaseBTCPrice();

function CoinbaseBTCPrice(){
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json",
    success: function(bitcoinPrice){
        console.log(JSON.parse(bitcoinPrice).bpi.USD.rate)
        }
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

For shorter version, you can you `$.getJSON` instead.

```js
$.getJSON("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json", function(currentPriceInfo){
  console.log(currentPriceInfo.bpi.USD.rate)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```